# Excel Data Validation multiple conditions not working ...?

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, multiple-conditions

I would like to do Data Validation on Cell E10 as follows:

1. F10 is blank (F10 = "")
2. E10 (self) is not greater than the maximum of range C9 to C100 (E10 <= max(C9:C100)
3. E10 (self) is not equal to B10 (E10 <> B10)

So, one would think that the correct formula for the custom data validation is:

```
=IF(AND(F10 = "", E10 <= MAX(C9:C100), E10 <> B10),1,0)
```

or

```
=(F10 = "")*(E10 <= MAX(C9:C100))*(E10 <> B10)
```

However, neither of these actually work in my case. I've extensively tested: each condition works fine on its own. (2) and (3) can be successfully combined as well. But, (2) and (3) are ignored the moment they are combined with (1), in which case only (1) is respected.

Can anyone help me to get Excel to respect all three the conditions?

Comment: have you tried just the `=AND(F10 = "", E10 <= MAX(C9:C100), E10 <> B10)` portion

Comment: Or `=SUMPRODUCT((F10 = "")*(E10 <= MAX(C9:C100))*(E10 <> B10))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
=AND((F10 = ""),(E10 <= MAX(C9:C100)),(E10 <> B10))
```

**but you must clear the ignore blanks checkbox!**

Comment: @ScottCraner  The first thing I tried was the formula in your comment..........it failed until I cleared the checkbox........I have stubbed my toe on this checkbox many times in the past.

Comment: Okay fair enough, I read it wrong. I was doing conditional formatting.  Stupid me.

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student!
Can you explain why that fixed it? What does the "ignore blanks" checkbox really do?